# Is there anyway Google App Engine apps can communicate or control Machine Learning models or tasks?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, machine-learning, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I want to use *Google's Machine Learning* thing with *App Engine* application written on python.

This application should retrain *TensorFlow* models before every use, because of the investigation nature (data clusterization using *Kohonen's SOM*).

I have following questions:

Can an *App Engine* based app to command *Machine Learning thing* to train some model with some input data?
Can an *App Engine* based app send some input vector into *ML thing* and get the result (what cluster this vector belongs)?
If everything is possible, how to do that?

If nothing from this is possible is there any other architecture I can use to make an *App Engine* based app use `TensorFlow`?

I talk about this thing:
[image]

Comment: What's the "Google's Machine Learning thing"? Are you asking if App Engine can communicate with tensorflow? Does framework like Spring XD sound reasonable in your case?

Comment: @LukaszTracewski - no, there is a thing in google cloud console named `Machine Learning`. There I can create some `models` and `tasks`. As I understand `models` is code based on `tensorflow`, while `tasks` is some tasks to train or predict. So I asking is there anyway App Engine application on python can control that `Machine learning`? For example, I will put there some model and whatever else, but how then I need to use it?

Comment: @LukaszTracewski - I read about Spring XD, but this is something way too different. I forced to use Google App Engine with Machine Learning.

Comment: Thanks, now I know what you mean. Never tried and as such I am unable to help you. You have inspired me to try it though :). Good luck.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski - if you success in anything, please tell me about your finds. I need to work with that, but no one know anything about it.

Comment: Look at https://cloud.google.com/ml/. It is now in public beta. I added a tag for your question: 'google-cloud-ml'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use App Engine to communicate with [Google Cloud Machine Learning](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/) (referred to as `CloudML` from here on).

To communicate with CloudML from Python you can use the [Google API client library](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/tutorials/python-guide), which you can use with [any Google Service](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started). This client library can also be used on App Engine, it even has specific documentation for this [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine).

I would recommend to first experiment with the API Client locally before testing it on App Engine. For the next part of this answer, I will make no distinction between using this client library locally or on App Engine.

---

You mentioned two different kind of operations you want to do with `CloudML`:

1. Update a model with new data
2. Getting predictions from a trained/deployed model

### 1. Update a model with new data

Updating a model on new data actually corresponds with two steps. First training the model on new data (with or without `CloudML`) and subsequently deploying this newly trained model on `CloudML`.

You can do both steps with the API client library from App Engine, but to reduce the complexity, I think you should start by following the [prediction quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/quickstarts/prediction). This will result in you having a newly trained and deployed model and will give you an understanding of the different steps involved.

Once you are familiar with the concepts and steps involved, you will see that you can store your new data on [GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/), and replace the different gcloud commands in the quickstart by their respective API calls that you can make with the API client library ([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/tutorials/python-guide)).

### 2. Getting predictions from a deployed model

If you have a deployed model (if not, follow [link](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/quickstarts/prediction) from the previous step), you can easily communicate with `CloudML` to either get [1)batch predictions or 2)online predictions](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/concepts/prediction-overview) (the latter is in alpha).
Since you are using App Engine, I assume you are interested in using the online predictions (getting immediate results).
The minimal code required to do this:

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from googleapiclient import discovery

projectID = 'projects/<your_project_id>'
modelName = projectID+'/models/<your_model_name>'

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()


ml = discovery.build('ml', 'v1beta1', credentials=credentials)
# Create a dictionary with the fields from the request body.
requestDict = {"instances":[
                    {"image": [0.0,..., 0.0, 0.0], "key": 0}
        ]}
# Create a request to call projects.models.create.
request = ml.projects().predict(
      name=modelName,
      body=requestDict)
response = request.execute()
```

With `{"image": <image_array>, "key": <key_id>}` the input-format you have defined for the deployed model via the link from the previous step. This will return in `response` containing the expected output of the model.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very useful, but not widespread info.